# Fastest way to get XAMPP or WAMP up on Win7 64-bit?

Tags: mysql, windows-7, 64-bit, xampp, wamp

I recently upgraded to a 64-bit machine, (I know I'm behind but everything was running and I'm cheap). I use XAMPP on my older machines to stand up local web dev and want to do the same on my new machine. However I'm having significant trouble getting XAMPP or WAMP to run properly under the 64-bit install. WAMP simply won't install saying that the setup files are corrupted and XAMPP installs but throws an error about running from the XAMPP directory on control panel launch and Apache will not stay running.

In my reading it seems that neither XAMPP or WAMP have been ported to 64-bit yet (not sure if this information is the most recent).

What is the quickest way to get one of these stacks up on a 64-bit Win 7 install, I don't really care if it has to run in 32-bit mode or not. Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT: Of course after posting I found the 64-bit download of WAMP, posting here for others who are search challenged like myself. I had been getting the sourceforge download links rather than the wampserver ones. Apparently the direct search engine links were defaulting to 32-bit or something.

Both versions here : http://www.wampserver.com/en/download.php

Comment: App installation is not programming related - voting to move to [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: Ok, new to StackExchange though, how do I go about doing the move?

Comment: Click the flag link (to the left of your username/avatar image) to contact a moderator if others haven't already voted.  Takes 5 votes...

Comment: @Fredrik, I meant moving the question to ServerFault, but yes installing WAMP was a breeze once I found the right download.

Answer (score 0):

download xampp from [here](http://www.apachefriends.org/download.php?xampp-win32-1.7.4-VC6.zip)

extract to someplace u like. then launch setup_xampp.bat from the extracted directory, follow instructions

double click on xampp_Start.exe to start, xampp_stop.exe to stop.

u can even extract this in a USB drive and when u change compus just launch the setup.bat once again. and u are good to go